# Configure routing

Tags: javascript, routes, http-status-code-404, angular

I have created a sample app using @RouteConfig and it working fine. See the url changes and view added according to configuration, but when I am refreshing the page it's showing a 404 error.

I am using WebStorm IDE to build and run the app.

The same problem happens with given live example on angular.io.

I have downloaded the sample code example for routing and navigation in AngularJS2 on https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html which given on angular.io and opened the project into WebStorm and ran it.

It working fine but after doing some routing and then refreshing the page it shows a 404 Error.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 (in default) uses **html5 pushState** for router states. Which means **actual url changes** between states.

For example for home page you may be in url: `/` and you click something, your address becomes `/newAddress`. This is done using pushState api and pure frontend. But if you refresh page, server tries to render the resource on `/newAddress` but, of course, there is no such resource on server. You need to configure your server to host `/` whatever the url is, but I don't know if it is possible or not in WebStorm internal server. You can install and use `superstatic` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superstatic).

**OR...** You can configure Angular 2 to use hashbang based urls (such as `/#/` and `/#/newAddress`). That way, you hit `/` every time from perspective of backend.

[This page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles) has detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've included a

```
<base href="/">
```

in your head section. Aside from that, we're going to need more information.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, add this to your bootstrap

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

```
import {provide}   from 'angular2/core';
    bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })]);
```

Now whenever you hit a refresh or a hard reload the default component defined in `@RouteConfig` would be loaded.

in your AppComponent :

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/login', name : 'Login' , component : Login , useAsDefault: true}
])
```